# left( \right) problem with Stix Math Two when \small applied to the group (Lualatex)

Tags: luatex, fontsize, unicode-math, stix, texlive-2017

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
{\small Small size
\[
    \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)   \left(\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{a}{b}}\right)
\]
}

Normal size
\[
    \left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \left(\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{a}{b}}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you compile it, you'll notice that parens are not scaled up correctly in the first one with `\small` directive. If you comment out `\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}` it works though. So, this seems to be a stix 2 problem. I use a fully updated LuaLatex (MacTeX 2017) system.

My questions a) is this a known issue? b) How can I work around this problem in a transparent way?

(I cannot switch to XeLaTex as I plan to play with some lua code.)

Comment: Apparently LuaTeX doesn't play well with the `ssty` feature. Not related, but the font name is `STIX Two Math`; use the proper name if you want to ensure code portability. And yes, it seems a problem with STIX Two Math, as it doesn't happen with XITS Math

Comment: with xelatex you [get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJg0P.png) which suggests it is a luatex or unicode-math issue rather than the font at fault.

Comment: Do you know a workaround to keep the font and the engine, but avoid this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the `+ssty` option which is used for sizes less than the base size; a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/stixfonts/tracking/86/) has already been filed at Sourceforge.

Here is an example to be compiled with `xetex` or `luatex` and yields different results.

```
\input ifxetex.sty

\ifxetex
  \font\extsymbolsA="STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;"
  \font\extsymbolsB="STIX Two Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=0;"
\else
  \input luaotfload.sty
  \font\extsymbolsA="STIX Two Math:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;"
  \font\extsymbolsB="STIX Two Math:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=0;"
\fi

\Udelcode`(="3 `(
\Udelcode`)="3 `)

\textfont3=\extsymbolsA
$$
\left(a\over b\right)
$$

\textfont3=\extsymbolsB
$$
\left(a\over b\right)
$$

\bye
```

### Output with `xetex`

[image]

### Output with `luatex`

[image]

The problem seems due to some interaction with the option and LuaTeX or `luaotfload`.

However, it only seems to affect parentheses and not the other delimiters:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
{\small Small size
\[
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)
\left[\frac{a}{b}\right]
\left\{\frac{a}{b}\right\}
\left\langle\frac{a}{b}\right\rangle
\]
}

Normal size
\[
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)
\left[\frac{a}{b}\right]
\left\{\frac{a}{b}\right\}
\left\langle\frac{a}{b}\right\rangle
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible workaround:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range={\(,\)}]{XITS Math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \Udelcode`(="4 `(
  \Udelcode`)="4 `)
}

\begin{document}
{\small Small size
\[
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)
\left[\frac{a}{b}\right]
\left\{\frac{a}{b}\right\}
\left\langle\frac{a}{b}\right\rangle
\]
}

Normal size
\[
\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)
\left[\frac{a}{b}\right]
\left\{\frac{a}{b}\right\}
\left\langle\frac{a}{b}\right\rangle
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's an acceptable workaround I think. Not sure if the XITS would be the best font to take the parens, as STIX Two is somewhat more similar to Cambria Math (to my eyes, I mean) but your solution seems quite transparent. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @balcinus XITS Math is based on the first version of STIX.

Comment: I know, but STIX Two looks "a bit" dissimilar to STIX version 1 IMHO. Not that it matters much: it's just parentheses involved in the workaround :)